Tableau map filter by top 10 stations by member type
I have a database with the following columns:
start_station_name
start_lat
start_lng
member_casual
total_count
I am trying to map them on tableau with start_lang and start_lng.
It is working, but I need to also filter by top 10 start_station_name for each value in member_casual.
I want the top 10 stations for member or casual.
I have tried putting member_casual in filter and top 10 like this. enter image description here
I have also tried putting the count in the filter but was only able to get the top 10 stations for both types of member_casual by manually clicking from the list.
enter image description here
I want the filter for member_casual to be visible, but when clicking on member or casual, I want the top 10 stations for either type. What should I be putting in the filter?
Below is what I have so far
enter image description here
